# Is rxplot time-synchronized?

Tags: ros, real-time, rxplot, timesynchronizer, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm monitoring a couple of message fields which come from different topics located in different machines. The question is if rxplot considers those messages having an stamp to paint the data.

If not, I wonder if there is any node to synchronize data from different topics without implement a new node using a Time Synchronizer
(http://ros.org/wiki/message_filters?distro=fuerte#Time_Synchronizer)

They both are desirable features if don't exist yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50562/is-rxplot-time-synchronized?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For its x-axis, rxplot uses the header.stamp from each message.

Synchronizing those time stamps between machines requires synchronizing the system times, which you should do anyway when running ROS.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-15**:
Wonderful. Thanks Joq. You always solve my doubts :-).